# Read file from model asp.net core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to read a json file from a class in Asp.net Core 1.1. The file is in the "wwwroot" of my mvc project.
I know I can take a dependency injection of IHostingEnvironment in controller, pass it down to my class, and access to WebRootPath, but I want to be able to instantiate my class outside a controller, e.g., inside another class.
How can I read a file which is in wwwroot folder inside my class?
Destination folder example:

> wwwroot/keywords/keywords.json.

If I try to inject IHostingEnvironment in constructor of my class, I will need to pass a HostingEnvironment instance when I instantiate my class.

```
public class AppTweet
{
  private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
  public AppTweet(ITweet tweet, ICollection<string> keyWords, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
  {
     _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
  }
}
```

I call my class in a controller that passes down the `hostingEnvironment`, but I want to decouple this behaviour, because I need to instantiate this class outside a controller. E.g.:

```
public class Article()
{
  public Article()
  {
    var appTweet = new AppTweet(new Tweet(), new List<string>, new HostingEnvironment()); 
  }
}
```

If I do this way, HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath is null

**EDIT**

Maybe I don't need Dependency Injection. I just want to read a file inside the wwwroot folder, but I don't know how to access this path both in development and in server
When I try

```
`var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\wwwroot\keywords\keywords.json")`;
```

the file var does not read the project folder in my development machine. The path I want to read form is something like E:\SOLUTION_FOLDER\PROJECT_FOLDER\wwwroot\keywords, but it reads from E:\SOLUTION_FOLDER\wwwroot\keywords, and does not include the project folder.

**EDIT 2**

I think DI is not suitable in this case.
This is a personal project of my own. What I'm trying to do is populate some properties in this class. E.g.: summary of my class:

```
public class AppTweet
{
  public AppTweet (ITweet tweet, ICollection<string> keyWords)
  {
    //Read a json file from wwwroot and populate NotDesiredKeyWords property
  }
  [NotMapped]
  public IEnumerable<string> NotDesiredKeyWords { get; set; }
 }
```

This class `AppTweet` must have access to this json file, that is like a configuration file, because it will always have to read these values. I know I can hard-code the values in the class (it will be faster), but I prefer to do it in a json file, so I don't have to compile the project if I add some value.
From what I could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) , Dependency Injection takes care of instantiate your class, and you can't have params in your constructor with no default values.
I need (not need but it's the more reasonable way to me) instantiate this class myself. And maybe instantiate this class inside another class, outside the controller. So, the only thing I want is to have access to the web root folder `wwwroot` (or some other folder) where I can put this json file, and it must work both in my machine and in the server. Which `path` I can pass to `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)` in order to read this file?

Comment: Why not just pass the path itself, or even the full filename, if that is all that AppTweet needs to know?

Comment: Or just use `Dependency Injection` for your AppTweet and pass in the `HostingEnvironment` instead of instantiating a new one

Comment: @PeterB, how I can pass the path to work both in development and in production? If I do var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\wwwroot\keywords\keywords.json");, then it skips the project folder in the path, and just read the solution folder. I did not test this in production. Could it work?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk If I pass HostingEnvironment in another constructor overload, how can I use the variable _hostingEnvironment if the instance was invoked with the first constructor (not the one which receives HostingEnvironment)? I am so confused...

Comment: @Porkopek why do you need it all in the constructor just call a method with the other parameters and use the construcotr for DI

Comment: *“but I want to decouple this behaviour, because I need to instantiate this class outside a controller”* – Misconception: If you instantiate it yourself, you are actually coupling it, since you are no longer using dependency injection.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I need to pass these parameters in constructor, because I receive the values from another class. I don't see how I can instantiate my class something like var appTweet = new AppTweet(tweet, keywords) and then access to _hostingEnvironment that only exists if the container instantiates the class

Comment: @poke Maybe this is the real problem. I am totally new to DI. The only thing I want to is to be able to access the wwwroot folder

Comment: It would help if you gave more context to what you are actually doing. What is that `Article` class and what are you using it for that you need to access that json file there?

Comment: @poke The AppTweet class is a model, and I need to populate some properties of it with some data included in a json file. So, I need to read this json file in order to populate this properties. The json file is stored at wwwroot folder in asp.net core project. I don't know how to access the wwwroot path inside my class. In controller I can access through HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, but in a class instantiated outside a controller, how can I do the same thing? And the Article class calls AppTweet

Comment: Models shouldn’t have such dependencies on other components. Consider having something else, e.g. a service, which has the purpose of filling the model with the data from the JSON file instead.

Comment: @poke I'll think about it. I didn't think about create a service just to read the file. Thank you. I'll tell you if it worked this way. But is not a way to read a file from that folder directly from a class? Regardless if it is a good or bad practice?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but you should avoid doing it automatically. That just couples your type against your environment which makes it hard to port and difficult to test. If you have some other component responsible of filling that model though, you can have other means of creating the models without coupling it to the existence of a file.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core provides [File Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers) for such cases. In your scenario you need the instance of `PhysicalFileProvider` class (it is used to access the actual or physical file of the system). It could be created directly as

```
IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider("root path");
```

or as your need to access files in `wwwroot`,  the `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` extension property may be used:

```
//
// Summary:
//     /// Gets or sets an Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider pointing
//     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath. ///
IFileProvider WebRootFileProvider { get; set; }
```

The possible way how to read your file:

```
// using System.IO;
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

// IHostingEnvironment env
...

var fileProvider = env.WebRootFileProvider;

// here you define only subpath
var fileInfo = fileProvider.GetFileInfo("keywords\keywords.json"); 

var fileStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Also, note that you need to add `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical` package as a dependency.

---

If you want to create instances manually, then you need to pass dependency in cascading way... (and the instance of `YourService` should be created in the same manner or passed into another class as the dependency via constructor using DI...)

```
public class YourService
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public YourService(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
    public Article CreateArticle()
    {
        return new Article(_env);
    }
}

public class AppTweet
{
  public AppTweet(ITweet tweet, ICollection<string> keyWords, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
  {
     // read file here for example
  }
}

public class Article()
{
  public Article(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
  {
    var appTweet = new AppTweet(new Tweet(), new List<string>, hostingEnvironment); 
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do I receive this IHostingEnvironment env in my class when my class has a constructor that receives another params? Sorry for my lack of understanding in DI.

Comment: actually [default DI implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) in ASP.NET Core supports only injecting dependencies via constructor

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, I only can  inject dependencies in a class with a constructor not invoked by me? What if I want to receive the FileProvider in a class that I need to instantiate myself (i. e., through the "new" word)? Can't I? My class is a model that needs to read a file from system in order to populate some properties, and instead of hardcoding the properties (they are List<string>), I decided to put them in a file. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @Porkopek I have updated answer, but anyway, suggest you read more about what is DI and how it is working...

Comment: thanks for your update. So, with this in mind, I think DI is not suitable in this case, because I think it adds a lot of overhead for such a simple case. And at the end, it's like a whiting that bites its tail, I need to let the controller or a service instantiate the class for me. I made a EDIT 2. Could you please read it and make a suggestion?